# Why video can't changed resolution in camera app android 2.3?

Tags: android, android-camera

Code set resolution:

```
private void setResolutionCamera(int G) {
        Camera.Parameters cp = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Size> sl = cp.getSupportedPictureSizes();

        int w = 0, h = 0;
        boolean exist = false;
        int i = 0;
        for (Size s : sl) {
            // if s.width meets whatever criteria you want set it to your w
            // and s.height meets whatever criteria you want for your h
            i++;
            if (i == G) {
                w = s.width;
                h = s.height;
                exist = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (!exist) {
            for (Size s : sl) {
                w = s.width;
                h = s.height;
                break;

            }
        }

        cp.setPictureSize(w, h);

        mCamera.setParameters(cp);
    }
```

I set size: 2560x1920, but video result still is 640x480 .
Why video can't changed resolution in camera app android 2.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shooting still images is different thing from recording videos as the latter requires more performance due to continuous stream of data needed to be processed. So you cannot just set anything and expect it to work. Basically unless your device clearly announces in specs that it is capable of doing so high resolution video recordings, you shall expect lower resolution being used.

If you targetting API11 or higher you can use [getSupportedVideoSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes%28%29) to supported video frame sizes instead of calling `getSupportedPictureSizes()` which is for stills.

Comment: cp.getSupportedPictureSizes(); exists size: 2560x1920

Comment: size: 2560x1920 is a example, other size: 1280x960,..., video result still is 640x480.( caputre image is ok)

Comment: This is for **still** images (hence the name of the method you call  Not video. Use `getSupportedVideoSizes()` (if you can)

Comment: Call requires API level 11 (current min is 9): My app run on android 2.3